# Angular $http.post request send double request.?

Tags: angularjs, http, post, request

I am using Angular `$http.post` request and my response come's after approx `5-8 min` so Angulars fails here because when response not comes in particular time than it send back 2nd request how can we set time for request's response come to wait ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a timeout property in $http which you can use.

example with `get` below

```
app.run(function($http, $q, $timeout){

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.get('/path/to/api', { timeout: deferred.promise })
    .then(function(){
      // success handler
    },function(reject){
      // error handler            
      if(reject.status === 0) {
         // $http timeout
      } else {
         // response error status from server 
      }
    });

  $timeout(function() {
    deferred.resolve(); // this aborts the request!
  }, 1000);
});
```

read more about it in [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: I have to mention above for `POST` request. Can i it works for POST request also ?

Comment: yes post request also do accept the config parameter.. the sequence of parameters you can check on angular-site